# LLVM: How to use LIBOMP_ARCH to cross compile libomp for riscv64

Tags: openmp, llvm

I'm reading [the LLVM documentation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/openmp) on how to build libomp in the LLVM repository. I've set `LIBOMP_ARCH` to "riscv64", and the cmake output shows

```
-- LIBOMP: Target Architecture  -- riscv64
```

However, after I run make, the library built appears to still be for x86.

```
$ objdump -f install/lib/libomp.a

.
.
.

z_Linux_asm.S.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000
```

Can anyone offer advice on how to properly use LIBOMP_ARCH to build for riscv64?